# Armature vertex slide constraint

Tags: armature, vertex-groups

I know how to vertex slide vertices in edit mode using "gg", but if I attach an armature bone to those vertices, is there any way to constrain the bone to slide those vertices along the edge, since currently I can't seem to find a constraint that will do that.

Comment: I don't think so, as edge sliding is a modeling feature (I didn't know about "gg", thanks), but if you need your mesh to be modified by an animation tool, I would try some shape key setup. Then you could make the bone movements drive the shape key animation, perhaps.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into that, the problem is I need to export it to Unity and didn't think shape keys worked for exporting.